# How to determine whether a variable is a decimal and it is less than 0.01 in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, boolean, decimal

How to determine whether a variable is a decimal and it is less than 0.01 in PHP?
If I write

```
if($balance<0.01)
```

Will a

> true

value be returned if

> $balance

is not a decimal at all?

Comment: please clearify your usage of *decimal*. Do you want to check if $balance is any number, e.g. -1, 0, 1.1, 13e7, etc? Or do you want to check for a specific *type* of number, e.g. floats, integers.

Comment: Is `$balance` supposed to be a monetary value? You almost certainly don't want to be using floats for this. Check out the bcmath extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use
    if( is_numeric($balance) && $balance < 0.01 )

http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$balance` will be typecasted to whatever is needed for the comparison. In your case, any integer will do, e.g. a $balance of `1`, `1.1` or `'1'` will all evaluate to `false`, regardless of their initial type. Consequently `0 < 0.1` will evaluate to `true`, because it will not check the type.

See the [PHP manual on Comparison Operators](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and the [type comparison table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). Also, See these functions for checking types

- [`is_int()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to find whether the type of a variable is integer
- [`is_float()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) to find whether the type of a variable is float/decimal

Example:

```
var_dump(is_int(1));   // true
var_dump(is_int(1.0)); // false
var_dump(is_int(1.1)); // false
var_dump(is_int('1')); // false

var_dump(is_float(1));   // false
var_dump(is_float(1.0)); // true
var_dump(is_float(1.1)); // true
var_dump(is_float('1')); // false
```

Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be easier to just check for `if(!($balance > 0))`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the is_real() function:

```
if(is_real($balance) && $balance<0.01)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try **is_float()**

```
<?php
$balance=2.75;
if(is_float($val) && $balance<0.01) {
 echo "is decimaland less than 0.01 \n";
}else {
 echo "is not decimal and greater than 0.01 \n";
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php

Comment: but what if it's an int value: 0, shouldn't that match?

Comment: I missed that one, maybe we can just put another criteria, and if $balance<>0

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, which was a straight forward yes/no: it depends.

If it's any type of number, like float, double or integer then php will perform as expected. Even if it's a string that php can interpret as a number, that'll work. If it's any other string like just $balance = "whatever", then this will return true so you would do a type checking if you expect this, in the fashion suggested by the other answers.

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more examples on what different operands produce.