# Decimal validation + PHP?

Tags: php, validation, decimal

How to do decimal number validation in PHP?

(The decimal point is optional)
it should accept ...
0 ,
1 ,
2 ,
0.123 ,
0.2 ,
12.34 etc.

Comment: See this related quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138899/how-to-determine-whether-a-variable-is-a-decimal-and-it-is-less-than-0-01-in-php/2138917#2138917

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would any of these suit your needs?

- [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)
- [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: xcellent ... thanx a lot... such a fn. was available? i was googling like anything... !

Comment: @dev646: Make sure you read the comments on the is_float function page. They are really helpful

Answer (score 5):

Answers for english locale have already been posted. The [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)::[parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) takes care of other locales, if you need such behaviour:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de-DE', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL);
if ($formatter->parse($value) !== false) {
    # A correct numeric value in german locale, like '12.345,00001'
}
```

Comment: I've been [playing with this](https://3v4l.org/IqgOB) and in fact it's more a tolerant parser than a proper validator. That can suit your needs or not.

Answer (score 4):

suggested is_float/is_numeric won't work, because is_float doesn't accept request parameters (which are strings) and is_numeric will accept something like "+.1e0" which is not what you want. The reliable way is to use regular expression for validation, for example

```
 $is_decimal = preg_match('/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $some_string);
```

the expression may vary depending on your needs. For example, the above will also accept "000.00" or "111111111111111".

Comment: -1 `if ((float)$a==$a)` would be acceptable, but not regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

Use [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)...